# Dataloader Insert Problem

Tags: apex, data-loader, csv

I'm trying to insert an Excel data in my org via Dataloader. But, when i try to use INSERT with the .csv file, i can't find the *'State__r:State__c:Code__c'* in the mapping field.

> Error> State: id value of incorrect type

I'm trying to insert these fields (The Object name is 'DistributionCenter__c'):
[image]

The spreadsheet is given via exercise in the course i'm doing, and it tells me to input all the information inside my org. But, i recieve an error when i try to map the *'State__r:State__c:Code__c'* with only *'State__c'* or *'Code__c'*, there's no option to use the 2 of then together.

I've searched on the internet but couldn't find a solution for this. The exercise told me to create inside Salesforce, a custom object called: DistributionCenter__c with 2 custom fields: 'Code__c' (Text, with External Identifier) and 'State__c' - Lookup (State__c). That Lookup is related to another custom object called State__c they told me to create.

The photo below will show how exactly the spreadsheet is:

[image]

Tried to use Upsert but no success. What can i do to solve this?

Comment: What object are you trying to insert/upsert? Can you screenshot the api names of the field you are trying to insert/upsert? Hard to help you if we don't know your backend fields

Comment: Added the fields on the question above my friend! It's a little more clear now? The object name is DistributionCenter__c

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I think you can't done this upload via data loader, Because `Data loader` works in "object specific' scope. You can't update the data for parent object fields from child object due to those fields are not available in `field mapping` section on `data loader`.

As per you're statement the field `State__r:State__c:Code__c` is not possible available in object `DistributionCenter__c`. Please double confirm whether it's `State__r.State__c` & `State__r.code__c` (May be possible available in `State__c` object)

Because if it's available in `DistributionCenter__c`, It's available as just `Code__c` & `State__c`. The term `__r` is used to point a Custom parent object from child object in `SFDC`

Please let me know if it helps.